# Performance issue with swf having text content while using in page Flip class

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a pageflip project and have 15 swf. Some of the swf which having the image content are loading(fliping effect) too smoothly , but if the swf having text content are loading very slowly.

```
var ocf:Object = PageFlip.computeFlip (this.pageCorner.clone(),
                                                        this.lastFlippedCorner,
                                                        this.width/2,
                                                        this.height,
                                                        !this.tearActive,
                                                        1);

                 PageFlip.drawBitmapSheet (ocf,
                                            this.render,
                                            this.bitmapData[frontIndex],
                                            this.bitmapData[backIndex]);
```

Any one please tel me what are the possible error while handling the swf with image and text content. Is there any difference in process of these two kind of SWFS

http://code.google.com/p/ricardo-flex/source/browse/trunk/Libro1/com/foxaweb/pageflip/PageFlip.as?r=7

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, this kind performance issue is caused by **not** setting `swfObj.cacheAsBitmap` property to true. Flash player has to recompute the positions of each vector element(text, shapes etc) on each frame update.

One solution would be setting cacheAsBitmap to true for the loaded swfs.

Comment: might need to make sure the font is embedded for this to work properly. Does cacheAsBitmap work on system-fonts?